# Show date picker on "activated" input field only

Tags: javascript, events, calendar, focus

I am trying to create two date input fields by using jquery-ui's datepicker() function, bot fields have the id of "datepicker": `<input type="text id="datepicker" name="publishUp">` and `<input type="text id="datepicker" name="publishDown">`

I tried to attach a function to the event focus as following, hoping to show the calendar only on the "activated" field, but it doesn't work. I am wondering where might be wrong?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        $("#datepicker").focus(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only showing when the input field is activated is the default behavior of the datepicker. Take the datepicker out of the event handler.

You shouldn't have multiple inputs with the same ID; the `$("#datepicker")` selector will only find the first one. If you want multiple datepicker inputs, use a class instead. So the HTML should be:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="publishUp">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="publishDown">
```

and the jQuery should then be:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        // options
    });
});
```